# Javascript Confirm box working wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, anchor, confirm

Hi all I am working in angular js , I want to add confirm message when click delete button

I tried this code :

```
<a data-ng-click="removeTodo(this)" href="javascript:;"
onclick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ?')">Delete</a>
```

This is shown *ok* and cancel *button* with the confirm box , if i click the *ok* button it's going to next process , but if i click the *cancel* button then it's same as going to same process  confirm box was not hide ( The *ok* button will return true , but same as cancel button will be return true not a false)

But it's working good when i used this below code on click my delete button

```
 $scope.removeTodo = function (Student) {
        if (!confirm("Do you want to delete this ? ")) {
            return false;
        }

   //please think , I added Some code for next process in here 
};
```

What is the problem ? what i missed ? Why my first code was not working ?

Comment: what does the parameter used for in `removeTodo`?

Comment: Don't worry the removeTodo code was working , But my anchor tag code was not working ,and removeTodo has return gridview row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `return false` is same as preventing the default action and stopping event propagation - which will prevent the handlers attached to ancestor elements from being executed... but in your case both click handlers are attached to the same element.

So even if the confirm returns false the angular click handler will get executed.

Comment: @RameshRajendran why don't you add the confirm code in the `removeTodo ` handler itself

Comment: So my second code is only for the correct way ? my first code not working on angularjs ?

Comment: Okay I understand you . But i am waiting for another answers . Thanks +1

Comment: But i have one doubt . Is it possible to add and will call  two js method on click event in one button ?

Comment: Your example was good . But my question something like just change . See this sample : http://jsfiddle.net/Y5aaj/4/ . Is it possible ? (but it's not working)

Comment: @RameshRajendran no it is not since `onclick` is a javascript handler it will not find the method in the scope object

Comment: @RameshRajendran because it uses inlined javascript

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39246/discussion-between-ramesh-rajendran-and-arun-p-johny)